# Cloning an active ipython kernel?

Tags: python, ipython

Let's say you have an ipythonqt shell open, and the shell is running a script. Is there a way to clone the shell in realtime (i.e. open another ipython shell such that it contains copies of all the objects currently associated with the memory state of the first shell/kernel)? The purpose of this (among other things) would be to permit the inspection of the progress that the original shell is making in running its script. Thanks.

Comment: Does os.fork() not work?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - the script would be running, precluding the execution of any commands in the shell. I think in this scenario, only the shell menu options would be available (i.e. various magics).

Answer (score 2):

The standard mechanisms for cloning a running process is called forking. But going this way all interactively the way you seem to be describing it will probably be a painful road to go.

What would be pretty simple to implement in my opinion is to create a new thread (using the `threading` standard package) in your python script that contains a call to an interactive shell ( along the lines of `import code; code.interact(local=locals())` or `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` ). You must know that while your interactive shell is actively working, though, your main thread won't be running because of the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

You may better be implementing some kind of time-based monitoring instead of this kind of solution, though. Something along the lines of:

```
if loop_number % 1000 == 0:
    print(x)
```

or

```
import time
timestamp = 0
[...]
if timestamp + 5 < time.time()
    print(x)
    timestamp = time.time()
```

Answer (score 2):

IPython is designed around an interpreter kernel with multiple consoles. When I start

```
ipython console
```

it reports in the banner text:

```
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-6795.json
```

So in another shell I run `ipython console --existing kernel-6795.json` and then can type in one shell

```
pid = os.getpid()
```

and in the other shell:

```
print pid
```

without getting a NameError. As I've never used this feature before, I did look at how it was implemented as processes: there are two instances of `ipython` but only one `python`. Indeed, `os.getpid()` gives the same PID in both shells.

**However**: If one shell is running code, the second shell will block until the first shell returns to the command prompt. I don't know how the more event-driven `ipython qtconsole` handles this yet.

Comment: Thanks, msw - interesting stuff. However, as you pointed out, the fact that one shell is blocked until the other finishes executing is major hindrance here...